# General enum member containing other members

Tags: vb.net, enums

Let's say I declare the enum as follows:

```
Private Enum Visiblity
    Invisible = 0
    Visible = 1
    VisibleMinimized = 2
    VisibleMaximized = 3
End Enum
```

As you can see 2 and 3 are just more specific types of Visible, but they still fall in the Visible category.

Let's say I declare a new Visibility enum called temp, and initialize it to VisibleMaximized.
Then I want to query temp to see if it's visible (ANY type of visible).
Yet when I query if temp = Visible, it returns false.

My question is how do I create my enum so that I can have specific members AND general "category" members?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `If temp > Visibility.Invisible Then`

Comment: If you prefer, you can also used [`Flag`ged enums](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/enum-statement#example-5).

Comment: The Flagged enum is what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: No problem.  Good luck.